# Assign Variable To Data Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I am returning 2 results from a SQL Stored Proc -

```
Select SUM(abcd) from rstuv
Select SUM(lmnop) from zxy
```

Then in my C# I am assigning those to `Data Tables` like so

```
DataTable firstreturnedresult = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable secondreturnedresult = ds.Tables[1];
```

Question being how can I assign a decimal variable to the `SUM()` contained in the `Data Set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries shown are using the scalar function SUM so the result is a datatable consisting of a single row with a single column. To get that value and assign it to a decimal variable you could write:

```
decimal sum1 = Convert.ToDecimal(firstreturnedresult.Rows[0][0]);
```

This works correctly only if your database table contains at least one row to SUM on. If the database table is empty then the first column of the returning table contains the value DbNull.Value and you need to watch for that and avoid a conversion that would trigger an exception

```
decimal sum1 = 0;
if(firstreturnedresult.Rows[0][0] != DBNull.Value)
   sum1 = Convert.ToDecimal(firstreturnedresult.Rows[0][0]);
```

Consider also to change how do you retrieve your values. Instead of building all the infrastructure required by an SqlDataAdapter you could opt for the simplicity of an SqlCommand and a call to ExecuteScalar

Something like this

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(abcd) from rstuv", connection);
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 decimal sum1 = result == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(result);
```

Comment: I think its better to use `coalesce` instead.

Comment: Well, of course, but this means changing the query. At this point then it is better to change the whole code and use ExecuteScalar as explained from in Habib's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `ExecuteQuery` against your SQL Command. Use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method on your command. This will give you one single value back.

```
decimal sum = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```